# Remove raw text with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider this piece of code :

```
<div id="apar">
     This text is to be removed 
     <span>
         Random content
     </span>
     <span>
         Random content
     </span>
     <div>
        .....
     </div>

</div>
```

How could I remove "This text is to be removed" text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **.contents()** in jquery in the context because it gets the children of each element in the set of matched elements, including text and comment nodes.

```
$('div').contents().first().remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/8jb0qpk3/)